# Modifying Spotify Context Menu via App

Tags: contextmenu, spotify

Is there a way to access/modify/add items to the context menu within the Spotify environment?

In other words, is it possible to make an app that while running allows me to, as an example, to go to a playlist, right-click a song, and have an item in the context menu called 'my context item,' which would would show an alert?

*From my experience the 'apps' live in their own window only, so I guess my question is can an app affect or source global environment/variables?

Example screen shot of what I would like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNAg6.png

Answer (score 0):

In short, but using a lot of words so Stack Overflow will accept this as an answer: No, this isn't possible. Sorry!